# Move files from sub-folders to root folder of archive files

Tags: archiving

I have some archive files and in each file there is a subfolder. I want to move files from subfolders to root folder of archive files and delete subfolders.

for example:

```
in lossless.rar
\my music\love.mp3
--->
\love.mp3
```

Hope someone know a solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You do not mention the type of your archives but from your example I assume that you use RAR files on Windows.

First you must create a temporary folder (eg. `C:\TempDir`) where you will do your job.

After this, you can use the following procedure:

- extract all the files without their paths in `TempDir`:

`rar e lossless.rar C:\TempDir\`

- delete the original archive: (BE SURE TO HAVE A BACKUP!)

`del /Q lossless.rar`

- add the files back without the path info: (otherwise you'll end up with c:\tempDir in your archive and you don't want that)

`rar a -ep lossless.rar c:\TempDir\*`

Of course, if you have a lot of archives you can automate the above steps by putting them in a batch file (eg. `RemoveRarPaths.cmd`) and have the archive name as a parameter. Then you can use it with `RemoveRarPaths.cmd myRar.rar` or more powerful: `RemoveRarPaths *.rar`

For your convenience the batch file should look something like:

```
rar e %1 c:\tempDir\
del /Q %1
rar a -ep %1 c:\tempDir\*
```

DISCLAIMER> Written from top of the head - not tested, no error handling, parameter checking etc. - just to show you the idea. Be sure to have backups & use at your own risk.